# Anaconda Navigator installed successfully but not opening in Elementary OS Hera. How can we resolve this?

Tags: command-line, thirdpartyapps, python, shell, qt

I installed anaconda navigator and it installed successfully too. But when I write anaconda-navigator in terminal and press enter, the following screen comes but the anaconda-navigator does not start:
[image]

I do not know that it is an anconda related problem or OS related.

It is neither running in root or as normal user. If someone can guide me through this, I will be very grateful to them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to run `anaconda-navigator` as root.

You'll want to make sure that you have installed the application as a normal user and *not as root*.
So don't prefix the command to run the installer with *sudo* but just run it with your current user's permissions.

Once you're installed, try activating the Anaconda virtual environment before and then running the application.
This should add the program to your `PATH`.
The steps below activate Anaconda's virtual environment and start `anaconda-navigator`.

1. If you installed Anaconda in your home directory in a folder called `anaconda3`, the default location, then use the following command.

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

2. Now run `anaconda-navigator`.

```
anaconda-navigator
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I installed and uninstalled Anaconda several times. It was only then I realised that the program installation was as root. That was the reason it was not letting me open it as root. But when I install it as normal user, the problem is solved. I am now able to run anaconda-navigator from the terminal and use Anaconda. Thank you for writing answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got that figured out! I've updated my answer to include the fact that Anaconda shouldn't be installed as root.